# Hiding files even from authenticated users using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to use settings in my `.htaccess`-file to exclude certain files from being displayed.

- For some files (here `data/important.json`) I want that even authenticated users are exceluded from viewing the content those files.
- For other files (here `showerror.php`) I'd like to give access to everyone.

The .htaccess-file in my root directory contains:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/showerror.php noauth=1
#SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/data/important.json noway=1

Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require user TestUser
Allow from env=noauth
#Deny from env=noway
```

The `.htaccess`-File of the folder `/data/` contains:

```
<Files "important.json">
#Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

It seems that the `Satisfy any` allows authenticated users to view the file. So is there a way to also exclude authenticated users from viewing the content of `important.json`?

Comment: What if you do `Satisfy all`?

Comment: Than only the access to `showerror.php` is possible,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply overwrite the [require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) of your root-`.htaccess` with the following require-setting in the `.htaccess` of your subdirectory:

```
Require all denied
```

Also see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

If you'd like to do this file by file, use:

```
<Files "important.json">
  Require all denied
</Files>
```